# Migrate load balancing to Azure Application Gateway

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway, azure-load-balancer

I have a standard load balancer existing in our environment and looking for ways to migrate to the Azure Application gateway. What would be the best way to minimize downtime and have a smooth transition?

The only I can see is deploying the application gateway and configure it and then delete the Azure Load balancer

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to put Application Gateway in front of the Load Balancer and simply use load balancer as a backend. that would be the least disruptive scenario.

After this setup is working you can configure additional backend bypassing the load balancer and remove your load balancer